# function/loop within gregexpr R

Tags: r, regex

I have a messy gregexpr call that looks like the below (it matches on any single or mutiple numbers that come before any of the following units listed in the unit vector below):

```
sub_matches <- as.character(regmatches(tolower(data$Dose.taken), 
        gregexpr("[0-9]+[0-9]g|+[0-9]g|[0-9]+[0-9]mg|+[0-9]mg|+[0-9]gm
            |[0-9]+[0-9]gm |[0-9]+[0-9]grm|+[0-9]grm
                |[0-9]+[0-9]ml|+[0-9]ml|[0-9]+[0-9]iu|+[0-9]iu
                    |[0-9]+[0-9]mls|+[0-9]mls|[0-9]+[0-9]gl|+[0-9]gl
                        |[0-9]+[0-9]l|+[0-9]l|[0-9]+[0-9]sheet|+[0-9]sheet
                            |[0-9]+[0-9]mcg|+[0-9]mcg", 
                                tolower(data$Dose.taken))))
```

I would like to wrap this in a function or loop so that It cycles through the following unit vector. However the below does not work in its current form. How can I tidy this up?

```
unit <- c("g","mg","gm","grm","ml","mls","l","mcg","iu","sheet")

i<-1

for(i in 1:length(unit)){

sub_matches <- as.character(regmatches(tolower(data$Dose.taken), 
        gregexpr("[0-9]+[0-9]paste(unit[i])|+[0-9]paste(unit[i])",tolower(data$Dose.taken))))


 }
```

Comment: Can you provide some example data for your `Dose.taken` column? I suspect you could perform the same matches with a much smaller regex.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to utilize a character vector to store the *units*, i'd play with [`paste0`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/paste.html) or [`sprintf`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sprintf.html).

```
regex <- sprintf('\\d+(%s)', paste(unit, collapse='|'))

sub_matches <- 
   regmatches(data$Dose.taken, 
     gregexpr(regex, ignore.case=TRUE, data$Dose.taken))
```

Otherwise, simplify your regular expression (*based off your statement above*):

```
sub_matches <- 
   regmatches(data$Dose.taken, 
     gregexpr('\\d+(gm?|grm|iu|l|mcg|mg|mls?|sheet)', ignore.case=TRUE, data$Dose.taken))
```

Answer (score 1):

Agree with hwnd! My twopence:

1. Your regex [0-9]+[0-9] can be replaced with [0-9]+ only.
2. Avoid loops: `paste(paste("[0-9]+",unit,sep=""),collapse="|")` which gives
   `"[0-9]+g|[0-9]+mg|[0-9]+gm|[0-9]+grm|[0-9]+ml|[0-9]+mls|[0-9]+l|[0-9]+mcg|[0-9]+iu|[0-9]+sheet"` .. and this can be then be used with the (regmatches,gregexpr)

Disclaimer: I would have placed this as a comment to hwnd's answer if I had the reputation to do so.